# mySQL single table summation

Tags: mysql

I have a single table "transfers" with columns (_from,_to,amount). For a given user I need to list all other users, their total amount transferred with this user, and their total amount transferred.

For example, if "transfers" was:

```
| _from | _to | amount |
------------------------
|   A   |  B  |  100   |
|   B   |  A  |  100   |
|   A   |  C  |  300   |
|   B   |  D  |  500   |
```

The result set for a query on user "A" would be:

```
| user  | myTransfers | totalTransfers | <--- same for whoever you query
----------------------------------------
|   A   |     500     |      500       |
|   B   |     200     |      700       |
|   C   |     300     |      300       |
|   D   |     0       |      500       |
```

This seemed trivial at first but I can't seem to get anything to work. Am I wrong to just throw subqueries at this? Or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Could you please explain your result set? It's not at all clear how you derived it.

Comment: can u explain values in mytransfer column ?

Comment: totalTransfers is the sum of all transfers of which the user was involved in (as the sender OR receiver). So, in the example result set A's total transfers are 100+100+300 (from transfer 1,2,3 respectively).

Comment: but myTransfers is more strange

Comment: myTransfers is the sum of all transfers of which the user was in (as the sender or receiver) AND the other party was the queried user. For example myTransfers for B is 200 since A was involved in transfer 1 and transfer 2 (totaling 200 of the total 700 he transferred).

Comment: so in this case, the result is a simple for a query on user A, right ?

Comment: Right. The query is for a particular user - in the example "A".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it, but you may find something easier.

The subquery does a "flattening" to get all possible users (from or to) as users.

```
select 
  user, 
 --here you choose the user you wanna query
 sum(case when correspondant = 'A' or user = 'A' then amount else 0 end),
 sum(amount)
from
 (select 
    _to as correspondant,
    amount, 
    _from as user
  from Table1
  union all
  select
    _from as correspondant,
    amount, 
    _to as user
  from Table1) s
group by user
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6856ed/46)

Comment: Awesome. I finally got a solution using a bunch of subqueries but it's pretty unwieldy.